"I don't like no whips and no chains." connotaion
"I don't like no whips and no chains."
How does this double negative construction differs to "I don't like whips and chains." from connotaion, grammar accuracy, usage prevalence? Could you provide more similar examples?

"I don't like no whips and no chains" means "I don't like any whips and chains at all." "I don't know nothing 'bout birthin' no babies" = not a darn thing at all = I lied and will be less than useless to help you (from the film "Gone With the Wind.")

A better translation into standard English might be "I don't like whips or chains." Another example: "We don't need no education" from Pink Floyd's Another Brick in the Wall.

The source would be good; I think the popular Jack Harlow song is "I don't like no whips and chains". It's non-standard but could be the feature of many dialects; but without knowing whether you've read it in Dickens or heard it in a rap song, it's hard to be precise. (Bonus points for "grammary accuracy" which isn't quite right, but sounds good.)

It would be hugely helpful if you would say where the quotation comes from, so that we might get some social context.
But in general, so-called "double negatives" like "I don't like no ..." are perfectly normal in many non-standard varieties of English, in many different parts of the English-speaking world. In those varieties, in general, there is no special meaning attached to using the construction: it is simply one of the ordinary ways of saying a negative.

We don't need no stinkin' badges!

https://genius.com/Sinneyy-lovin-on-me-nik-plunk-5-lyrics

OK. So it's a song lyric. Asking about the grammar and nuance of meaning in  poetry and lyrics is mostly a waste of time.

True, but there are plenty of non-poetry examples that the OP might just as easily have asked about, and your answer would hold. It might be nice, though the OP didn't seem to explicitly ask about it, to address the fact that "no" is attached to both of the objects. Seems to me this just rhetorically adds emphasis, like "I don't want any arguing or any complaining or any eye-rolling."
